# Is the WCF REST Starter Kit still current?

Tags: asp.net, rest

I've been researching the possibility of building a REST service in .net and came across the WCF REST Starter Kit.

It looks useful but the latest preview release came out over a year ago and there doesn't seem to be a production release. Does that mean it's not being worked on by MS any more? Has it been superseded by something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server side stuff from this starter kit has been rolled into .Net 4.0.

Comment: SO, if I want to use the project templates can I still install the REST starter kit alongside VS2010?

Comment: I believe the project templates are already available in VS2010 by default.

Comment: I have VS2010 installed, and I don't have any project templates related to the REST Starter Kit.